# Counting the number of lines in a file using try and catch

Tags: java, file, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I need to try count the number of lines in a file while using "try" and "catch". This is what I have so far. Hoping I could get some help. It just keeps timing out.

```
public class LineCount {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"));

        int count = 0;
        //String line;
        //line = in.readLine();
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            count++;

        }
        System.out.println("Number of lines: " + count);

    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}



}
```

}

Comment: Why try-catch relevant to thw counting here?

Comment: You are never calling for the next line so the `Scanner` is staying on line one (meaning there is ALWAYS a "next" line). Add a call to `in.nextLine()` in your `while` loop. This will move the "pointer" of the scanner to the next line.

Comment: @code_mechanic I get an error saying "LineCount.java:16: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
   Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"));" If i dont use try-catch

Comment: I think, @Zephyr already answered the problem in your code, all I was referring to the statement of question, it was unclear.

Comment: There is an easy three-liner for this involving `LineNumberReader`.

Comment: Adding on to @user207421, all you have to do is `LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));while (lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE) > 0) {}
    int numOfLines = lnr.getLineNumber() + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

It times out because you do not advance the `Scanner`. If you enter the while loop you will never exit it.

Also it would be better if you use `BufferedReader` as is is faster than a standard Scanner. Although if the file is small, maybe for readability purposes you do not. But this is up to you. Anyway.
Here you go:

```
//this is the try-with-resources syntax
//closing the autoclosable resources when try catch is over
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FileName"))){
    
    int count = 0;
    while( reader.readLine() != null){
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("The file has " + count + " lines"); 
}catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("File was not found");
    //or you can print -1;
}
```

Probably your questiong has already been answered and you should not ask already answered questions before you search, for a while at least.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are doing everything but consuming the newline character. To do this with `java.util.Scanner`, simply run `in.nextLine()` in your `while` loop. This `Scanner.nextLine()` method will return all characters before the next newline and consume the newline character itself.

Another thing to consider with your code is resource management. After opening the `Scanner`, it should be closed when it'll no longer be read. This can be done with `in.close()` at the end of your program. Another way to accomplish this is to setup a try-with-resources block. To do this, just move your `Scanner` declaration like this:

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"))) {
```

Regarding the need for the try-catch block, as part of the Java compilation process, checked-exceptions will be checked if they are caught or thrown from a method. Checked-exceptions are everything that are not `RuntimeException`s or `Error`s.